# Calling a java script function inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print something inside my html from a java script. I did this but it don't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p>I am trying to print <script>go();</script></p>



<script>

function go() {
 document.write("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're function hasn't been defined yet in the example you are posting, so call to go effectively does nothing, change the ordering of your script tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

function go() {
 document.write("Hello World!");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>I am trying to print <script>go();</script></p>



</body>
</html>
```